# Xcode can’t launch project for debugging

Tags: xcode, macos, lldb

I’m using Xcode 4.6.3 to build a library for OS X. My project includes a target called `LibraryTest`, which is a command-line app to test the functionality of the library. Both the library and the test app build fine, but when I try to run the app it quits immediately and the debug console shows:

```
error: failed to launch '/Users/bdesham/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Wavelength_and_Spectrum_Library-byosniusyaoidgdcpzwzuzkitzgv/Build/Products/Debug/LibraryTest'
-- error: Host::LaunchProcess (launch_info) => pid=0,
path='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/Resources/debugserver'
err = error: ::posix_spawnp (
    pid => 98649,
    path = '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/Resources/debugserver',
    file_actions = 0x10b09e268,
    attr = 0x10b09e2a0,
    argv = 0x7fe2701377e0,
    envp = 0x0 )
err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009) (0x00000009)
error: failed to launch '/Users/bdesham/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Wavelength_and_Spectrum_Library-byosniusyaoidgdcpzwzuzkitzgv/Build/Products/Debug/LibraryTest'
-- error: Host::LaunchProcess (launch_info) => pid=0,
path='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/Resources/debugserver'
err = error: ::posix_spawnp (
    pid => 98649,
    path = '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/Resources/debugserver',
    file_actions = 0x10b09e268,
    attr = 0x10b09e2a0,
    argv = 0x7fe2701377e0,
    envp = 0x0 )
err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009) (0x00000009)
```

(Line breaks added for readability.) I have the Xcode 5 DP installed, so I tried removing Xcode 4 and reinstalling it from the Mac App Store, but no dice. Deleting `DerivedData` didn’t help either. Any ideas?

Comment: Too many [zombie processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process)? Next time this happens open the Terminal and run `ps aux | grep 'Z'`.

Comment: There were problems with iOS Simulator debug sessions leaving behind zombies earlier in the Mac OS X 10.8.x / Xcode 4.6.x versions but those should all be fixed with 10.8.4 and 4.6.3 AFAIK (I can't remember exactly when it was fixed off-hand.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Restarting my Mac seems to have fixed this.

Comment: This worked for me, too, very weird. What's weirder -- after restarting the old builds still failed but new builds made after restart worked. Huh?

Answer (score 4):

Check "Build Settings" -> "Provisioning Profile". It should be "none" or some provisioning for Max OSX (if you're building for the app-store) . In my case it erroneously had "iOS Ad Hoc Provisioning Profile". This resolved this problem for me.

---

Note: I found this out by checking the syslog ("cat -f /var/log/system.log" in terminal, then start app). It wrote a crash report which had "...embedded provisioning profile not valid:..." among other lines. Checking the app container itself indeed showed an "embedded.provisionprofile" file, which triggered me to check the build settings for it.

Comment: Just a small note, you can replace `cat` with `tail`, for `tail -f /var/log/system.log`, so you can get live updates to any new entries in that file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by updating iOS. I was using JailBreak iOS version.

Comment: The question refers to Mac OS X.